# Arithmetic properties of progressions

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

Let $a$ and $b$ two relatively prime numbers. We set $N_{a,b}:=\{a+kb, \, k \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Suppose that there exists a multiple of $b$, namely $hb \in N_{c,d}$ for some relatively prime numbers $c,d$. It is obvious that $b$ and $d$ have no common factors. But I have to show that there exists two numbers $t,s \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $c-a=tb-sd$.

I have no clue, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

From $hb \in N_{c,d}$, you have 
$$
hb = c+\hat k d
$$
for some $\hat k$.
Since, as you say, $(b,d)=1$, there exist $m$ and $n$ such that
$$
a = mb+nd
$$
and so
$$c-a = hb-\hat k d - mb - nd = (h-m)b-(\hat k+n)d.$$

Comment: @TheWanderer Hey there! Was my answer helpful?